# Can't Plug in Stored Variable into Numpy Sine Function

Tags: python, variables, numpy, matplotlib, cgi

I'm trying to take an entry from an html page form and pass it to a cgi script where it takes the entry and gives the sine function of the entry.
The entry would be:  x  OR  x**2  OR  (1-x)/x...

I have it working until I try to use variable (lala) in the np.sin().  It returns a blank page.

Here is some code.

```
import cgi
import cStringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

def doit():
    lala = form.getvalue('x')
    x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
    y = np.sin(lala)

    format = "png"
    sio = cStringIO.StringIO()

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.savefig(sio, format=format)

    data_uri = sio.getvalue().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
    img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}" alt="sucka" />'.format(data_uri)

    print("Content-type: text/html\n")
    print("<title>Try Ageen</title>")
    print("<h1>Hi</h1>")
    print(img_tag)
    print("<h1>This is the sine of %s</h1>" %xx)

doit()
```

As I've said it will return the variable lala in the html code that reads: Here is the sine of (x, for instance).

It will not let me plug the lala variable into the y = np.sin(HERE).  Even if lala's returned value is x.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get from `lala = form.getvalue('x')`?  Print it.  Most likely it's a string, like 'x'.

`np.sin()` expects a number or an array.

```
In [785]: np.sin(1)
Out[785]: 0.8414709848078965
In [786]: x=np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 4)
In [787]: x
Out[787]: array([-3.14159265, -1.04719755,  1.04719755,  3.14159265])
In [788]: np.sin(x)
Out[788]: 
array([ -1.22464680e-16,  -8.66025404e-01,   8.66025404e-01,
         1.22464680e-16])
```

To work in `plt.plot(x, y)`, `y` should have the same number of elements as `x`, for example `y = np.sin(x)`.  I don't see you doing any sort of calculation like that.

`np.sin('x')`, using the string 'x', is not going to work.

If you want to use a string from the html form to select array for plotting I'd suggest using a dictionary mapping:

```
dd = {'x': x, 'x2': x**2, 'x1': x/(1-x)}
y = sin(dd[lala])
```

Comment: Trying all these.  As soon as I make the dictionary, the page won't pull up.  lala returns as 'x', yes.  y = np.sin(dd[lala]) is not working.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

`form.getvalue('x')` returns a string. You must convert it into a numpy array before passing to `np.sin()`. You get a blank page because the script crashes.